# css hover on elements issue in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm designing a html page with strict doctype and there's a form element in my page.

What I want to do is to change background-color of inputbox when mouse touches my form. I've done this with css :hover selector on form tag, but problem is that IE only understands hover on "a" tag!

I've googled my problem and what I found is to:

- using an htc file;
- using javascript to create a hover class on elements;
- creating a big "a" tag and put all elements inside it;

but I don't want to do any of these solutions!

Isn't there any better way to fix this problem in IE?

My HTML Code:

```
<form id="footer-search-form" title="Search" action="#action">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="footer-search-input" id="q" name="Search"></input>
        <input type="button" class="footer-search-button" title="Search" value="Search"></input>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My CSS Code:

```
#footer-search-form:hover  .footer-search-button { background-color: #fff; }
#footer-search-form:hover  .footer-search-input { background-color: #fff; }
```

**Update**: and after hours of searching I did it by using js:

`onmouseover="this.setAttribute(document.all?'className':'class','footer-search-hovered');" onmouseout="this.removeAttribute(document.all?'className':'class','footer-search-hovered');"`

and

```
.footer-search-hovered .footer-search-input, .footer-search-hovered .footer-search-button { background-color: #fff !important; } /* For IE6 compatibility */
```

I hate it, but it seems that there's no better way...

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `.htc` fix? http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

Comment: I have some bad experiences with `.htc` fixes. most of the times they fix a simple issue by creating another complicated issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has supported `:hover` on any element since IE8 (or even IE7? I don't remember), which has been released for over three years. Admittedly far too many people still use IE6 (mostly because IE doesn't have an auto-updater - it *really* needs one), but for something as simple as this aesthetic effect you really don't need to worry about support in old relics.

Comment: Like I said, IE6 is unsupported by many sites, as it should be. If you want to support IE6, why not go the full length and make it work in IE1?

Comment: Please stop making fun of me! I hate IE, the time that I have to spend to fix my pages bugs in IE is too much more than the time that I spend writing my code. My boss has forced me to make it compatible with IE6, because of high rate of visitors with this stupid browser!

Comment: lol, well to state the bleeding obvious, if you made it work in IE in the first place (with no IE-specific "hacks"), it'd automatically work in other browsers. Your boss makes me glad that I am my own.

Answer (score 2):

You're really only going to run into trouble [if your users are using IE6](http://caniuse.com/#search=hover). The majority of web developers nowadays don't even bother providing support for such an old browser, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Of course if I was going to design my own webpage I would completely ignore all versions of Internet Explorer. But unfortunately I'm forced to design this page to work with all browsers, even IE6.

Comment: I would consult whoever's telling you to develop to IE6 and tell them [it's really not worth the time](http://www.ie6countdown.com/). And about answering questions; no worries, here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work